# Wired connection randomly drops

Tags: networking, drivers

I have Ubuntu 16.04, and a wired connection that randomly drops.

I know there have been similar questions outthere. Most of the answers and solutions suggest dowloading the correct realtek driver (r8168) and blacklisting the r8169.

I have already tried that and it doesnt work.

Here is the output of several commands

sudo lshw -C network:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 0c
   serial: 40:8d:5c:de:1a:38
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.041.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=157.253.189.89 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:27 ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:fd8ff000-fd8fffff memory:fdffc000-fdffffff
```

ifconfig -a:

```
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:8d:5c:de:1a:38  
      inet addr:157.253.189.89  Bcast:157.253.189.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a672:3bb8:b3e1:fb55/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:46280 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:30716 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:31704375 (31.7 MB)  TX bytes:4968347 (4.9 MB)
      Interrupt:27 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:130416 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:130416 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:7132374 (7.1 MB)  TX bytes:7132374 (7.1 MB)
```

more /etc/resolv.conf:

```
 # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by      resolvconf(8)
 #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 157.253.79.100
nameserver 157.253.52.21
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search uniandes.edu.co
```

route:

```
 Kernel IP routing table
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref      Use Iface
default         host-1-189.unia 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
```

lspci | grep -i eth

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

dmesg | tail -f

```
  1914.107781] r8168: enp3s0: link up
[ 1914.107843] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
 [ 2390.147498] systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 5h 29min 49.440572s random time.
 [ 2390.288165] systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 58min 15.402284s random time.
[ 2411.870373] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[ 2411.885002] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[ 2424.596299] systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 29min 4.436112s random time.
[ 2430.562408] show_signal_msg: 36 callbacks suppressed
[ 2430.562413] vpnagentd[17744]: segfault at 6d ip 00000000004658a4 sp 00007f612827cd20 error 6 in vpnagentd (deleted)[400000+9f000]
[ 2434.448505] systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 2h 3min 37.434529s random time.
```

Comment: The question is tagged "network-manager". If you don't use NetworkManager, the tag is wrong which leads to wrong answers. If you use it, look at NM's log file (`journalctl -u NetworkManager`)